# Does this idea generally true ?!

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

Does $\int \limits_{a}^{b} f(t) dt \leq \int \limits_{a}^{b} g(t) dt \leq \int \limits_{a}^{b} h(t) dt$ Given that $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$?

If the above is true, could we say that :

$f(b)-f(a) \leq \int \limits_{a}^{b} g(t) dt \leq h(b)-h(a)$ if $f'(x) \leq g(x) \leq h'(x)$ ?!

Comment: Respectively: yes, yes. The domination property is known in calculus. I should add that the domination must hold everywhere on the domination (or at least almost everywhere).

Comment: For the second inequality, you need some additional conditions.  What is $x$ (one needs more care mixing definite integrals and indefinite integrals)?  You could use $f(b)-f(a)$ on the LHS and $h(b)-h(a)$ on the RHS.

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry, i will update the post

Comment: @MichaelBurr does it know hold true ?, i mean the second inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second inequality (assuming continuity and integrability where necessary and that $a\leq b$), since $f'(x)\leq g(x)\leq h'(x)$, we know that 
$$
\int_a^b f'(x)dx\leq \int_a^b g(x)dx\leq \int_a^bh'(x)dx.
$$
Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus gives us
$$
f(b)-f(a)\leq\int_a^b g(x)dx\leq h(b)-h(a)
$$
as desired.  So, yes, your statement is correct.

Comment: Provided that $a \le b$, of course...

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Use the first Theorem of Calculus which states that

if

1. $f $ continuous at $[a,b] $.
2. $f $ differentiable at $(a,b) $.
3. $f'$ integrable at $[a,b] $

then
$$\int_a^bf'(x)dx=f (b)-f (a) $$